# how to use the parameter value for dynamically built SQL queries inside postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to compile a postgresql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LoadData(tablename varchar(25), filepath varchar(35))
RETURNS void AS $$
declare

BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE 'Data is being loaded from an external file, please wait...';

COPY tablename FROM filepath DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;


RAISE NOTICE 'Data loaded successfully!!';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but it's giving an error like this

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "filepath"
LINE 9: COPY tablename FROM filepath DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

How to use both the in parameters in the COPY command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute dynamically built SQL queries use `execute`. `format` makes it easy and safe

```
create or replace function loaddata(
    tablename varchar(25), filepath varchar(35)
) returns void as $$
begin

raise notice 'data is being loaded from an external file, please wait...';

execute format($copy$
    copy %I from %L delimiter ',' csv header
    $copy$,
    tablename, filepath
);

raise notice 'data loaded successfully!!';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN